# How does IO-Link handle compatibility between different sensor brands and models

Tags: sensors, plc, codesys, iec61131-3

I am starting to study the application of [IO-Link](https://io-link.com/en/Technology/what_is_IO-Link.php?thisID=76) Sensors in a machine, in this case I will apply several types, such as inductive, optical, flow and pressure, this technology will help me to standardize the types of connections... but well...

Once the machine is programmed and the sensors parameterized, I understood that I could change the sensor for another one of the same model and brand without problems, that the IO-Link Master would reprogram this new sensor when detecting the change, but what if this sensor is not available on the market, if you only get another similar one from the same brand or, even worse, from another brand (obviously with the exactly same characteristics), what would the IO-Link master do?

- Would the master be able to reprogram this sensor and the machine would work again without any intervention?
- Would you have to change the PLC program to recognize the different sensor (change the [IODD file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IODD))?

In this case I will use Codesys 3.5, but I know that IO-link is a standard so I don't think that the type of platform should imply in a different situation.

Comment: In my experience: No, and yes. Even a sensor from the same manufacturer will have a different device ID and so the master won't try to restore from a backup it has saved.